# How do I extract values from <input> tags with same name?

Tags: jquery, html

I have either

1) multiple `<input type="checkbox">` tags which have same name

2) `<input type="radio">` tags which have same name

2) is trivial case, since radio buttons with same name can have only one button clicked.

the problem is case 1). here's what I came up with:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  alert(value);
});
```

with this, `value` stores only one item. If user have checked multiple items in same checkbox, how can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
    stack = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            stack.push($(this).val())
        }
    })
    console.log(stack)
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/anilov/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

using jquery [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selects all elements of type checkbox., [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selects checked checkbox. so you can combine this and use loop to get the values...

try this

```
$(':checkbox').click( function() {
   var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
    });

   console.log(val);
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/atV4C/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get checked values like this :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" checked="checked" title="1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" title="2" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" checked="checked" title="3" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" title="4" value="4"/>
```

**Script:**

```
var val = []
$("input[name='checkboxes']:checked").each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(val);
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/56XTZ/